# Tengo que realizar el siguiente programa:

Tags: python

Dado un número  entero  positivo    hallar  los números perfectos   menores que él. Un  número  es  perfecto    si  la  suma de sus divisores,  excepto él  mismo,  es  igual   al  propio  número.

-El código que he realizado para terminarlo es este:

```
contador = 0
try:
    numero = int(input('Introduce un número positivo: '))
    if numero < 0: 
        print('Error: Debes introducir un número entero positivo...')

    for i in range(1,numero):
        for d in range(1,i):
            if i%d == 0:  
                contador+=d 
            elif i == contador:
                print('El número',d,'es un número perfecto.')
            

except ValueError:
    print('Error: Debes introducir un número entero positivo...')
```

Alguien me puede decir porque no me funciona?. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casí lo tienes, pero te has liado un poco. Te voy a ir señalando los errores simplemente modificando tú código lo menos posible:

```
contador = 0
try:
    numero = int(input('Introduce un número positivo: '))
    if numero < 0: 
        print('Error: Debes introducir un número entero positivo...')
    else:
        for i in range(1,numero):
            if numero % i == 0:
                contador+=i

        if numero == contador:
            print('El número',numero,'es un número perfecto.')
        else:
            print('El número',numero,'No es un número perfecto')
            

except ValueError:
    print('Error: Debes introducir un número')
```

### try / except

Esta sintaxis sirve para capturar errores, puede tener uso en tu ejemplo, pero solo es para capturar un error y poder manejarlo. El único caso que se puede dar para usarlo es que alguien te pueda introducir un texto no númerico, por ejemplo "hola". En ese caso le indicarás que tiene que introducir un número.

### if

En el siguiente `if` ya solo te queda comprobar si el número es positivo o no. En  el caso de que no lo sea, ahora sí devuelves el error.

### Bucles for.

Aquí es donde te haces el lio.

1. Python es un lenguaje que funciona con identación. Por tanto si quieres hacer la comprobación al final. Necesitas sacar `if` del bucle for, y ejecutarlo cuando se haya comprobado todos los divisores.
2. Siguiendo sobre este `if` lo correcto es (aunque también es valido poner `elif`) que si solo hay dos output posibles, evalues un `if` y una vez acabado, si su resultado no es `True` entonces que vaya directamente al `else`
3. Por último el bucle `for` que en mi código ya se ejecuta antes de los ```if````anteriormente mencionados. Solo necesitas hacer uno, ya que con ese uno iras comprobando todos los divisores y sumandolos a *contador* aquellos que sean 1 para comprobar al final si es perfecto.

He probado el ejemplo con un número perfecto como el 6 y funciona.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido de mucha ayuda ^^